# IIF MDX statement, active flag = 1 or 0

Tags: if-statement, ssas, mdx

I've got a product dimension in my SSAS project and i've got an active flag attribute.

I'm trying to make my cube say "Active" or "Not active". I'm trying to accomplish this through a calculated member script.

```
IIF([Dim Product].[Active Flag]=1, "Aktiv", "Ikke Aktiv")
```

As you can see, I'm a complete noob, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would move this logic upstream e.g to a SQL View feeding the Dim Product.  I would add a calculated column there and use that to create a new attribute in the dimensions.

Many client tools have problems with Calculated Members.